# Is there a C library for machine learning algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, beginner, c

Are there any machine learning libraries for C.
Specifically interested in unsupervised learning.

Comment: Is C++ acceptable? There are plenty of libraries for C++.

Comment: yeah, i am interested in knowing C++ libraries as well

Comment: Why do you want a C library?

Comment: @ChandanVenkatesh Since you are also interested in C++, please include this in your question and tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a detailed table about different machine learning libraries on different languages:

https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning

Checkout C version [here](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning#c) and C++ version [here](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning#cpp).

Personally speaking, try [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/index.html) ! OpenCV provides multiple machine learning implementations including [KMeans](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#kmeans), [kNN](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html), [SVM](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html), etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use SVMs: [`libsvm`](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) is written in C.